# Capture all repeated groups

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to capture all string inside the curly braces in this string:

```
_{test_1} != '' || _{_str_test_2} != 'Yes' && _{_test_str_3} == 'Yes'
```

This is my regex pattern:

```
(?:.*(?:_{(.+)+})+.*)+
```

But the problem is, it only captures the last match.

How can I capture all of the matches ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = "_{test_1} != '' || _{_str_test_2} != 'Yes' && _{_test_str_3} == 'Yes'";
$pattern = '#{(.*?)}#s';

preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Welcome...! @MonkeyDNaruto